# Como aplicar um estilo em dois elementos diferentes usando :hover?

Tags: css

Considerando:

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1">
    <p>Elemento 1</p>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <p>Elemento 2</p>
</div>
```

Como eu posso usar o `:hover` no `div1` para mudar propriedades de estilo do `div2`?
Tentei o seguinte, mas sem sucesso:

**CSS**

```
#div2, #div1:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Até o momento que o mouse entra no `div1`, funciona como eu quero, porém quando ele sai um problema surge: o `div2` continua com o `background-color: white`. O que devo fazer (usando CSS) para fazer o fundo branco do `div2` sumir junto com o fundo branco da outra div?

Comment: Você quer que o background da #div2 se altere quando passar o mouse em cima da #div1 (voltando ao normal ao sair)?

Comment: @Wakim, exatamente.

Comment: Apaguei minha resposta, não tinha intendido direito a pergunta, acho que o @Wakim já respondeu o que você precisava ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O problema é que está aplicando a mesma regra para dois seletores independentes, usando a "," não é criada nenhuma relação entre os seletores.

Usando o seletor de irmão (General Sibling Selector) "~" você consegue aplicar a regra de `hover` no irmão cujo seletor esteja a direita. Dessa forma a regra fica:

```
#div1:hover ~ #div2 {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Lendo a regra seria:

> Quando passar o mouse em cima do elemento com id `div1`, selecione todos os irmãos cujo id seja `div2` e aplique a regra abaixo.

Dê uma olhada nesse [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55kKr/) para ver o código funcionando. No caso coloquei o fundo preto para ter contraste.

Existe uma variação, o seletor de irmão direto "+" que pega apenas os irmãos subsequente e antecedente aos elementos do seletor da esquerda, pode ser útil também.

Além desses, existe também o seletor de filho direto (Child Selector) ">", pode ser usado também, mas não para esse caso específico. E o seletor de descendente (Descendant Selector) " " (espaço), que é mais abrangente que o child selector.

Para mais detalhes de uma olhada em:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors
4. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors

Comment: Perfeita resposta, mas só para esclarecer, o `~` pega todos os seletores no mesmo nível e o `+` pega os seletores que estão imediatamente acima e abaixo?

Comment: Exatamente, mas precisa pensar em árvores (O DOM é uma árvore), correto sobre o `~`, no caso do `+` eles estão no mesmo nível, mas a grosso modo é o nó "esquerdo" e "direto" na sub-árvore que compõem todos os irmãos.