# Aplicar Estilo CSS aos elementos do Razor ex: EditorFor

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-5

Como faço para aplicar um estilo a todos os `EditorFor` da minha `View`?

**Exemplo do campo**:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Photo, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
```

tentei fazer assim mas não deu:

```
<style>
    Html.EditorFor{
        width:500px;
    }
</style>
```

e também assim:

```
<style>
    EditorFor{
        width:500px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: relacionado: [Como aplicar um estilo em dois elementos diferentes usando :hover?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26684/como-aplicar-um-estilo-em-dois-elementos-diferentes-usando-hover)

Comment: @Virgilio isto funciona com elementos com tags como 'div, a, p' e etc mas neste meu caso não... pois aí é utilizado o Razor

Comment: por isso é relacionada, independente de qualquer coisa input, div etc são `tags html`, e se enquadrão. O problema é saber o que aquela linha vai gerar? você poderia colocar isso porque o `EditorFor` gera a partir de um tipo e os tipos de uma classe pode e devem variar. Que `input` ele gera?

Comment: Vc diz pra mim trocar o EditorFor pelo Input? No <Style>?

Comment: Na vdd este tamanho é só pra teste pra ver se funciona

Comment: você dê uma olhada na resposta?

Answer (score 1):

O [EditorFor](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-editor-editorfor) gera `tags HTML` e são nelas que aplicamos configurações de *tamanho*, *cor*, *estilos* ([`css`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)), etc.

A tabela abaixo é como se comporta o [EditorFor](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-editor-editorfor) conforme o tipo de dado:

```
| --- Property DataType --- | ------ Html Element ------ |
| string                    |   <input type="text">      | 
| int                       |   <input type="number">    | 
| decimal, float            |   <input type="text">      | 
| boolean                   |   <input type="checkbox">  |
| Enum                      |   <input type="text">      |
| DateTime                  |   <input type="datetime">  |
| ------------------------------------------------------ |
```

<sup>**Referencia da tabela site:** [**tutorialsTeacher.com**](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-editor-editorfor)</sup>

---

#### Para atribuir [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) com tamanho padrão siga os exemplos abaixo:

Colocar tamanho em todos os `input`

```css
input {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Colocar tamanho em todos os `input` do tipo **text**?

```css
input[type="text"] {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<input type="password" />
```

<sub>**Observação:** somente os `input` do tipo `text` recebe o tamanho padrão de `500px`</sub>

Com esses dois exemplos pode criar [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) para determinados tipos de dados, ou para um determinado tipo de `tag` [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/).

***Referencias:***

- [Personalizando os Campos inputs dos formulários utilizando CSS](http://www.webcis.com.br/personalizando-os-campos-dos-formularios.html)
- [As tags HTML para formulários e sua estilização com CSS](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/cssforms.php)
- [HtmlHelper.Editor:](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-editor-editorfor)
- [EditorExtensions.EditorFor Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [HTML5 Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/)
- [CSS Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)